# User selectable widgets in Umbraco 7

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

We are looking at Umbraco as a possible alternative to our current CMS which was developed in house and which although powerful, is dated now and becoming more difficult to maintain.

One really good feature which we would be loth to lose is the widget feature. Using this,  we can build a widget by defining a number of inputs (eg text fields, media picker, links etc) together with the html required to output the results (using placeholders to substitute in the content entered by the web content editors).

On the page, content editors can select which (if any) widget(s) to use, enter content into the inputs defined in the widget, and the page outputs this accordingly.

In other words, without resorting to programming, we can create widgets just by defining inputs and the output html in minutes.

Users can select widgets and their input is controlled and formatted.

Simple and effective.

Is anything like this available in Umbraco without having to develop new C# code for each widget? I have looked into using macros in a rich text field, but I can't see how they can be made editable using complex data entry as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the Macro in richtext,

In Umbraco you can use a picker/list view data type to select some "component/widget items" and for rendering it requires some code if more than one document type is allowed, if document type is x1 do code a1. 
Use (Partial view) Macro Files for reuse.
This is the closest to the "widget" function you want.

A other relatively new datatype in Umbraco is the Grid layouts, allow editors to create a Complex data, column structure with multiple data types. I suspect not comparable/useful for your "widget" function.